# ScheduledExecutorService: How do I catch its exceptions?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm currently working with an `ScheduledExecutorService`. I use it this way:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor;
public class ScheduledFanSpeedController implements Runnable {
.
.
.
public void start(){
executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 55, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

The `.scheduleAtFixRate` may throw a `RejectedExecutionException`. How or/and where would I catch this exception when it gets thrown on the n-th run of the task by the executor? Do I really have to mess with overriding for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this Constructor to inject your own implementation of a RejectedExecutionHandler:

[public ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,                            RejectedExecutionHandler handler)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(int,%20java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler))

So you would instead of using `executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);` write:

```
executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, new MyRejectedHandler());
```

where `MyRejectedHandler` would be an instance of your implementation of the interface [RejectedExecutionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html).

I used this once to handle congestion.

There are also predefined "policies":

- [ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy.html) (the default)
- [ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html) ( runs the Task on the Thread that called execute, blocking it, of course )
- [ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy.html) ( discards the Task that has been rejected )
- [ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy.html) ( adds the rejected task to the queue and discards the oldest task in the queue instead )

You would set them like this:

```
executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy());
```

> Do I really have to mess with overriding for that?

Not sure what you mean by that. But if you thought you have to extend ThreadPoolExecutor, then in most cases : no. That Family of classes is IMHO so neatly designed and complete that you nearly never have the urge to do that. It is almost like a construction kit which allows for a vast variety of behaviors. The most invasive implementation I had to do once was to inject my own ThreadFactory (for thread naming) and a RejectedExecutionHandler that removed optional low-prio tasks from the queue on congestion.

### Other Exceptions

If you want to catch Exceptions that arise inside the `run` method, then I suggest you enclose the body of it in try/catch. Which is ok for first shot. I tend to narrow down try/catch blocks to where they are really needed. This enables you to handle them on the executing Thread of the pool.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that possibility. That's exactly what I was looking for.